# Alignment of a list-style-image

Tags: html, css, html-lists, background-image

I'm wondering if there's a way to determine the horizontal and vertical alignment of the `list-style-image`?

Because at the moment, it looks something like this :

_ LIST TEXT

and I would like it to be like this

– List Text

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What does your html and css look like?

Comment: <ul>
   <li>Hello!</li>
</ul>

CSS :
ul{
 list-style-image: url(../img/my-personnal-bullet);
}

I want the list to look like this : - Hello ! , but (the hypen being my list-style-image) the style is like this :

_ Hello !

Comment: What are the dimensions for my-personnal-bullet ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try a couple of approaches, for example:

```
<h3>Using a list-style-image</h3>
<ul class="basic">
    <li>Hello!</li>
    <li>Good-Bye!</li>
    <li>See you later!</li>
</ul> 

<h3>Using a Background Image on li</h3>
<ul class="bg-img">
    <li>Hello!</li>
    <li>Good-Bye!</li>
    <li>See you later!</li>
</ul>
```

and look at the following CSS:

```
ul.basic {
    list-style: none;
    list-style-image: url(http://placehold.it/20x20);
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
}
ul.basic li {
    margin: 1.00em 0 0 0;
    padding: 0 0 0 0;
}

ul.bg-img {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
}
ul.bg-img li {
    background-image: url(http://placehold.it/20x5);
    background-repeat: no-repeat; 
    background-position: left center;
    margin: 1.00em 0 0 -30px;
    padding: 0 0 0 30px;
}
```

In the first case, you can make the list image a 20x20 px square for example and embed the hyphen in the center of the image.  However, if the font size changes, you won't maintain the vertical centering since the list image is pinned to the base line of the `li` element.

In the second example, turn off the list style and place a background image on the `li` element.  Again, embed the hyphen in an image, and position it left and center.  This approach gives you some control over the position of the hyphen motif by adjusting the left margin and padding of the `li` element, and the `background-position` property.

For reference, look at: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/JKZLe/

Answer (score 0):

This is controlled in webkit and mozilla, respectively, but the `-webkit-padding-start` and `-moz-padding-start` rules on `<ul>` and `<ol>` elements.  It can be overridden by `padding-left` (this will work in IE as well).

```
ul {
    padding-left: 40px;
}
```